# object assigned from data.table still "linked" to that data.table

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to `data.table`, and honestly don't use it much, but sometimes it is highly useful. I came across this [what I felt was an] oddity recently. I simply wanted to keep some names as a separate object that were later changed, but these were modified when I changed the `dt` names.

```
dt <- data.table(A = 1:3, B = letters[1:3], foo = paste0("bar", "baz", "bee"))

oldNames <- names(dt)
setnames(dt, c("A", "B"), c("notA", "notB"))
newNames <- names(dt)
```

This should be `FALSE` if oldNames is a separate entity

```
all(oldNames == newNames)
# [1] TRUE
```

Seems they have been modified...

```
> print(oldNames)
[1] "notA" "notB" "foo"
```

doesnt seem to be anything indicating that it is still linked to dt

```
class(oldNames) 
# [1] "character"
```

Just wondering what is going on here. Why is the `oldNames` object changed when modifying `dt`?  Shouldn't it be an independent object? And how would one break this link if they so desired?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the object in order for it to change when its reference is modified.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(A = 1:3, B = letters[1:3], foo = paste0("bar", "baz", "bee"))

oldNames.1 <- names(dt)
oldNames.2 <- copy(names(dt))

setnames(dt, c("A", "B"), c("notA", "notB"))

newNames <- names(dt)

newNames == oldNames.1
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

newNames == oldNames.2
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I am still unsatisfied as to why this behavior exists. I thought the whole point of data.table objects was that you didn't need to copy them entirely in the memory when you change them. Why would something like a character string of the list names continue to be updated after you have assigned it to another object? Perhaps its easier to ask "where/when would this behavior be useful?"  It certainly causes confusion, as objects in base R behave independent of one another.

Comment: Ha! just saw that this is the exact example used in the `copy()` function. "`A ‘copy()’ may be required when doing ‘dt_names = names(DT)’. Due
     to R's _copy-on-modify_, ‘dt_names’ still points to the same
     location in memory as ‘names(DT)’. Therefore modifying ‘DT’ _by
     reference_ now, say by adding a new column, ‘dt_names’ will also
     get updated. To avoid this, one has to _explicitly_ copy:
     ‘dt_names <- copy(names(DT))’.`"  Still don't understand why this is useful...